# Will it cause harm when abort ubuntu software upgrade halfway?

Tags: upgrade

Today I'm upgrading my Ubuntu software, but the net connection is slow. So I abort it use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Will it do any harm to aborting the upgrade process?

It's currently on this status:

```
Get:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main bash i386 4.3-7ubuntu1 [548 kB]
Get:2 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main dpkg i386 1.17.5ubuntu5.3 [1,936 kB]                        
Get:3 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main mount i386 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.1 [113 kB]                    q
Get:4 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main tzdata all 2014e-0ubuntu0.14.04 [181 kB]                    q
Get:5 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main util-linux i386 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.1 [450 kB]               
Get:6 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libapt-pkg4.12 i386 1.0.1ubuntu2.1 [633 kB]                 
1% [6 libapt-pkg4.12 469 kB/633 kB 74%]                                                              26.5 kB/s 2h 33min 29s^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry you aborted while the packages started to download, the packages are not in process of installing so it will not cause any problems. Try cleaning the partially downloaded packages (if there) in this folders

`/var/cache/apt/archives/` or `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial`

by using `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: So if I aborted while installing new packages, damages may be done?

Comment: if packages starts installing 'yes' you can deal with it by re-installing that package

Comment: If I aborted when install bash... How do I use /bin/sh in a terminal?

Comment: what do you mean by installing bash

Comment: sorry, I mean when install its upgrade package.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing has been installed, then you should not see any difference in system stability because it looks like you stopped it before the installation process began. However, you may have some incomplete downloads and you may need to run `sudo apt-get autoclean` to remove any incomplete downloads, or `sudo apt-get clean` to delete all upgrade downloads, before you will be able to complete the upgrade.